# how to publish persistent messages using Pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am using Pika to work with Rabbit MQ. I use the following to send a message to the broker:

```
channel.basic_publish('direct', 'samt_routing',json.dumps({'name':'reza','lastname':'rastgoo','id':i}))
```

before that I declare queue and exchange and bind exchange to queue as following:

```
channel.queue_declare(queue='Samt',durable=True)
channel.exchange_declare(durable=True,exchange_type='direct',exchange='direct')
channel.queue_bind(queue='Samt',exchange='direct',routing_key='samt_routing')
```

But when I restart the container all messages are purged.

Can I publish persistent messages to Rabbit with Pika?

Comment: How do you declare the queue?

Comment: @Klaus D for answer to your question, I edited the question from.

Comment: https://github.com/pika/pika/search?q=persistent

Answer (score 7):

https://github.com/pika/pika/search?q=persistent

```
basic_publish(
            exchange=exchange_name,
            routing_key=routing_key,
            body=body,
            properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                delivery_mode=pika.spec.PERSISTENT_DELIVERY_MODE,
                priority=headers.priority.value,
                headers=headers.dict(),
            )
```